# How to change the displayer of UniversalImageLoader?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

This should be very simple thing to do, but I can't find it. I want to show at some places in my app images with rounded corners. But not all.

The only place where the I see I can set the display is in the initial setup. Can't find other method. And I can't overwrite the initial setup, since it's set only when the configuration is null. I also don't find a method to change it in the DisplayImageOptions object used at initialization.

What do I do to change between rounded and not-rounded corners? Thanks in advance.

If necessary, this is the library I'm talking about: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure displayer in `DisplayImageOptions`, and you can customize `DisplayImageOptions` for every `displayImage(...)` call (just pass it to method).

When you don't pass `DisplayImageOptions` to `displayImage(...)` then default options from configuration are used (`.defaultDisplayImageOptions(...)`).

Comment: omg, I'm so blind!!! started looking if I can pass a displayer, then went to the init() method and wondered why I cant pass another config... :D whatever. Thanks very much.